# retrieving image thumbnail

Tags: android

Given the IMAGE_ID in by the ContentProvider, how do i get the thumbnail path of it?

```
 Cursor c = this.managedQuery(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, null, selection, null, null);

            while ( c.moveToNext()){
                String title = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.TITLE));
                String description = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DESCRIPTION));
                long imgId = c.getLong(c.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns._ID));
           ... }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look on this [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.html), there isn't any information about path to image in `MediaStore.Images.Media`.
You can try to look to the all columns in Cursor, maybe there is some information:

```
String[] columns = c.getColumnNames();
```